# Equivalent of egrep -o ".{0,4}TEST.{0,8}" in R

Tags: r

In bash it is pretty straightforward to search for a string and grab x previous or following characters.

For example:
Create simple string and store it in a file:

```
echo "AADfjalksdjfalskdfj 20 TEST Afasdlkfjasdf 50" > string.txt
egrep -o ".{0,4}TEST.{0,8}" string.txt
```

This returns:

```
 20 TEST Afasdlk
```

Any ideas on how to do this in R?  I can't seem to get grep or grepl to behave.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexpr()` and `regmatches()` in R to do this

```
str<- "AADfjalksdjfalskdfj 20 TEST Afasdlkfjasdf 50"
regmatches(str, regexpr(".{0,4}TEST.{0,8}", str))
# [1] " 20 TEST Afasdlk"
```